# ZMQ recv randomly picks up garbage data does any one know why?

Tags: c#, c++, network-programming, zeromq

I have a client server app which is sending data from a C# client to a C++ server.  When the server receives this data request, 9 out of 10 times it works ok, but there is always 1 time were there will be garbage data appended to the end of the received data on the server side.

for example instead of receiving a number 1 it will receive 1C or 1@????

Here are snippets of the client and server code, any help will be appreciated.

C# client

```
int flagSide = 1;

msg = name;
msg += "+";
msg += "qty";
msg += "+";
msg += flagSide.ToString();

ZeroMQ.ZmqContext context = ZeroMQ.ZmqContext.Create();

ZeroMQ.ZmqSocket socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ);

socket.Connect("tcp://111.111.0.111:5556");

socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg.ToCharArray()));

Thread.Sleep(1);

string reply = socket.Receive(Encoding.ASCII);

Console.WriteLine("Received reply = " + reply + "\n");
```

C++ Server

```
std::tr1::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> aMap;

zmq::context_t context( 1 );
zmq::socket_t responder( context, ZMQ_REP ); 

responder.bind ("tcp://*:5556");

while ( 1 )
{
zmq::message_t recvMsg;
responder.recv( &recvMsg );

t = static_cast<char*>( recvMsg.data() );

std::string s(t);

std::vector<std::string> strs;

boost::split(strs, s, boost::is_any_of("+"));

aMap["name"] = strs[0];
aMap["qty"] = strs[1];
aMap["flag"] = strs[2];


..........
```

outputing the split string in the server reveals that sometimes the flag or strs[2] receives the garbage data.

Please help me if you see something that I'm not seeing.

Thanks

Comment: Not knowing a thing about C# encoding to bytes, I don't suppose that thing null-terminates the resultant string? I don't see how it could, as the documentation for it says if the string is empty the resultant byte array is *zero* length (which would mean no terminator in the most-basic of conditions, much less one with actual content.). I could be wrong (probably am), but worth investigating. Perhaps building a string `s` from a range such as `std::string s(t, recvMsg.size())` would work better.

Comment: No you might be onto something, let me take a look into this

Comment: You both were indeed right, there was no null termination when the encoding was taking place and string message converted to an array. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, strings converted to bytes are not null-terminated, and c++ string expects a null terminated pointer.

So I presume what is happening here, is a buffer underflow. You are reading memory which does not belongs to the string.

Comment: I appended a null terminator like so msg += "\0"; to the end of the string in the C# client and it seems to have done the trick so far.  So I appreciate you help thanks much.